# Algorithm for fewest logins to online bank

Tags: python, algorithm

Below are a list of recurring monthly bills. The first number is the day of the month the bill arrives (first chance to pay it) and the second number is the due day of the month (last chance to pay it).

- 16, 1
- 2, 16
- 10, 25
- 31, 26
- 15, 31

The difference between the arrival and due date is always less than a month. I'm looking for an algorithm that, for any number of bills with any reception dates and any due dates, will:

1. produce a list of fewest possible login dates to the online bank where the bills are paid.
2. guarantee that no due dates are missed.

My idea so far is to look for a single date (or date range) on which as many as possible bills are between arrival and due date, and then repeat this process until the list is empty.

Is this the best approach? Is there an existing algorithm for this problem? What is it called? Code examples, if any, would be preferred in Python, PHP or just pseudo-code.

Comment: fewest possible logins as in "logging into a system where you can pay them"?. One other questions: Do they come in that format or is the month also known? 16 feb - 1march?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) If 2nd number is less than 1st number, 2nd number is next month.

Comment: Is this a static analysis task where the arrival dates are all known ahead of time, or could they change? I have a hard time imagining how you could beat "log in on the next due date and schedule for payment all bills which have arrived so far".

Comment: Yes. These are recurring bills with static dates. You would have to log into the online bank to check for unforeseen bills with unknown dates, which defeats the purpose of logging in as seldom as possible. (Unless all bills are notified by a separate channel such as email, but that's not part of the exercise.)

Comment: Your suggestion sounds simple and interesting, but why is it the correct one? To get the actual login dates out of your suggestion one would have to write a simple simulation, which I will try if no better alternatives show up.

Comment: This looks like *Set cover problem* which is NP-hard.

Comment: I'm not good at math (or the "NP" concept), but it looks like you may be right. Can anyone explain what this means with respect to writing code that solves the problem in an acceptable fashion? (In practice the number of bills will be small, like under 10 or 20, and all ranges fall within 1 and 31. So what you really want to find is if you can get away with a *single* login, which would be just heaven, or if not, two logins, or at worst three logins.)

Comment: @forthrin look at Said A. Sryheni's solution, it looks like this particular problem is a lot easier than the Set cover problem in general.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Your solution is not correct and here is why:

Suppose you have many days where the same amount of ranges intersect, and this amount is the maximum among all others. For example:

1. 1 -> 3
2. 3 -> 6
3. 6 -> 9
4. 9 -> 10

From what I see you you have the following days (**3**, **6**, **9**) where all of them have two bills to be paid, and no other day contains more bills to be paid. Now since you can't possibly determine which day to start with, you could for example choose day **6** and pay the bills (**2**, **3**). Next, you have no other option but to choose days **3** and **9** to pay bills **1** and **4** correspondingly. You used **3** days, while the answer is **2** choosing the first day to be **3** paying both bills **1** and **2**, then choosing day **9** paying bills **3** and **4**.

Anyways, I'm pretty sure I have an almost linear time solution for you.

First, let's make your input a little bit more clear, and add **30** (or **31** in case of 31 days month) to the second number if it is in fact smaller than the first one. Your example would look like this:

- 16 -> 31
- 2  -> 16
- 10 -> 25
- 31 -> 56
- 15 -> 31

My idea is based on the following 2 facts:

1. Whenever a login is made, it is always better to pay all the bills which are available, and haven't been paid yet.
2. When traversing the time line of the month from the beginning (day **1**) to the end (day **60**) it is always better to try and delay the logging process if possible; meaning that if the delay won't cause any due date to be missed.

In order to do so let's first assign a unique ID to each entry:

1. 16 -> 31
2. 2  -> 16
3. 10 -> 25
4. 31 -> 56
5. 15 -> 31

Let's use sweep line algorithm which generally solves interval related problems. Create a vector called **Sweep** where each element of this vector contains the following information:

- **ID**: The ID of the corresponding entry.
- **Timer**: Indicating either the first or the last day to pay a bill.
- **Type**: Just a flag. **0** means that **Timer** contains the first day to pay the bill number **ID** (first number), whereas **1** means that **Timer** contains the last day to pay the bill number **ID** (second number).

For each entry insert **2** elements to **Sweep** vector:

1. **ID** = ID of the entry, **Timer** = First number, **Type** = 0.
2. **ID** = ID of the entry, **Timer** = Second number, **Type** = 1.

After inserting all these elements to **Sweep** vector it will have a size equals to *2* x *number of entries*. Sort this vector increasingly based on the value of **Timer**, in case of a tie then increasingly based on the value of **Type** (In order to first check the start of an entry before its end).

Traverse **Sweep** vector while keeping a set containing the IDs of all the unpaid bills so far, let's call this set **Ready**. In each step you might deal with one the following elements (based on the **Type** we added):

- **Type** = **0**. In this case it means that you have reached the day of first being able to pay the bill number **ID**. Don't pay this bill yet. Instead insert its **ID** to our **Ready** set (idea 2).
- **Type** = **1**. In this case check to see whether the corresponding **ID** is inside **Ready** set. If it is not just continue to the next element. If it is in fact inside **Ready** set this means that you have reached the last day for paying a previously unpaid bill. You have no other option but to pay this bill, alongside with all the other bills inside **Ready** set at this day (idea 1). By paying the bill I mean to increase the variable containing your answer by one, and if it's important to you traverse **Ready** set and store somewhere that all these **ID**s must be paid at the current day. After doing so you have paid all the ready bills, just *clear* **Ready** set (erase all the elements inside it).

Every entry causes **2** elements to be inserted into the **Sweep** vector, and every entry will be inserted exactly once into **Ready** set, and deleted once as well. The cost for checking an **ID** inside **Ready** set is **O(Log N)** and it's done for every entry exactly once. The sorting operation is **O(N Log N)**. Thus, your total complexity would be: **O(N Log N)** where **N** is the total number of entries you have.

Python is not really my strongest programming language, so I will leave the mission of coding the mentioned algorithm up to you (in C++ for example it's not that hard to implement). Hope it helps!

---

**EDIT** (thanks to @Jeff's comment)

You can make your solution to be even **O(N)** using the following approach:

Instead of iterating over the events, you could iterate over the days from **1** to **60**, and keep the same handling method as I mentioned. This way we eliminated the sort operation.

To remove the **O(Log N)** factor from the inserting and checking operation we could use a hash table as mentioned by @Jeff's comment, or instead of a hash table you could use a boolean array **Visited**, with a vector **Ready**. you will insert **Ready** bills to the vector. When you need to pay bills you will simply iterate over the **Ready** vector and mark the bills inside it as visited in their corresponding indexes inside the **Visited** array. Checking if I bill has been paid can be simply done by accessing the corresponding index inside the **Visited** array.

The funny thing is that after writing my answer I came up with almost the exact same optimization as mentioned by @Jeff's comment. However, seeing that number of days is really small, I decided not to make my answer any more complex, and keep it easier to understand. Now that @Jeff mentioned the optimization I decided to add it to my answer as well. However, please note that with this optimization the overall complexity now equals to **O(N + D)**, where **N** is the total number of bills, and **D** is the total number of days. So, if **D** is quite large you will actually need to stick with the first solution.

Comment: A very thorough explanation. I'll have to set aside time to read through and fully understand it. Is this in any way similar to my own suggestion (see initial post)?

Comment: Actually no. I just updated my answer, and at the beginning explained why your solution will give a wrong answer on some cases. When you read and understand my answer I hope you could up-vote it and mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: I think you can technically make this O(N) (but with a large coefficient) by avoiding the vector (and thus the sort) and instead just scan the entire list of unsorted ranges for each day from 1 to 60. The Ready set can be implemented by a hash table with O(1) operation. It might beat O(N log N) if N > 3600 (that'd be a lot of bills though!)

Comment: @Jeff Sure your are 100% correct. I updated my answer with an approach a lot similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

The above code would give back answer as 2 only for the following mentioned input:

```
1. 1->3 (Bill A)
2. 3->6 (Bill B)
3. 6->9 (Bill C)
4. 9->10 (Bill D)
```

The explanation:
1. We get the first input bill as 1->3.
2. This bill gets added in it's first set: with period:1->3.
3. Next bill comes 3->6, it lies in the same period that is 1->3 as 
receiving Date of bill is same as end period of the bill.

```
set1:(1->3) { BillA, BillB}
```

4. Next bill is 6->9, this creates a new set:

   set1:(1->3){BillA,BillB}
   Set2:(6->9) {BillC}.
5. Next incoming bill is 9->10, which goes in set 2 only again due to the same reason as above.

   set1:(1->3){BillA,BillB}
   set2:(6->9){BillC,BillD}

I believe this is the correct solution as the problem really asks us to just identify number of disjoint sets.

Comment: The solution should provide a list of days to log in to the online bank. Sorry if this was unclear.

Answer (score -3):

Solution In Java:-

```
public class Ress {

    Set<Interval> intervals = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] input = {"16 1","2 16","10 25","31 26","15 31"};
        System.out.println(minimumLogins(input));

    }

    public static int minimumLogins(String[] input) {
        Ress r = new Ress();
        for (String s : input) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
            Bill b = new Bill(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());
            r.addToIntervals(b);
        }
        //If we have to print the dates on which to pay the bills, then it will be any date inside the different intervals.
        return r.intervals.size();
    }

    public void addToIntervals (Bill b) {
        Interval i = null;
        for(Interval in:intervals){
            if(in.canAddBill(b)) {
                i = in;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i==null) {
            i = new Interval(b);
            intervals.add(i);
        }
        i.addBill(b);
    }

}

class Bill{
    int receiveDate;
    int dueDate;

    public Bill(int a, int b) {
        receiveDate = a;
        if(b<a) {
            // adding to represent the date in next month
            b += 31;
        }
        dueDate = b;
    }
}

class Interval{
    int startDate;;
    int endDate;
    List<Bill> bills;

    public Interval(Bill b) {
        startDate = b.receiveDate;
        endDate = b.dueDate;
        bills = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addBill(Bill b) {
        bills.add(b);
        //Reset interval boundaries based on the newly added bill
        if(b.dueDate<this.endDate) {
            endDate = b.dueDate;
        }
        if(b.receiveDate>this.startDate) {
            startDate = b.receiveDate;
        }
    }

    public boolean canAddBill(Bill b) {
        /*
         * Bill can be added if it lies in the interval.
         */
        if(b.dueDate<=this.endDate || b.receiveDate<=this.endDate) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + endDate;
        result = prime * result + startDate;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Interval other = (Interval) obj;
        if (endDate != other.endDate)
            return false;
        if (startDate != other.startDate)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to find different disjoint sets of intervals for all bills in the input.

Comment: FYI: code-only answers are often frowned upon, even if commented. Consider providing commentary text to explain what the code actually does.